# iPhone 8 Jailbreak & remove carrier lock

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I bought an iPhone 8 from USA while i was on my exchange student period. The sales man at Target promised me that it is not carrier locked. So naturally, it's carrier locked.

So if i jailbreak my iPhone is it going to remove the carrier lock? I have been trying to find the answer but have not found it.

Comment: If you want to jailbreak even if it doesn't remove the lock, I recommend you to stay on the lowest firmware you can (ie. iOS 11.0-11.2.2, because only requirement is an exploit)

Answer (score 1):

No, jailbreaking your iPhone does not in itself remove the carrier lock.